# getting model attribute in jsp

Tags: jsp, attributes, jstl

I have been seen that use forEach statement to get model attribute

```
<c:forEach items="${userForms}" var="userForm">     
   // Do something
</c:forEach>
```

but If I have only one value

```
model.addAttribute("maxNums",5-searchAppVO.getFindCnt() );
```

How should I read only one value from jsp?

```
<input type="hidden" id="maxFileNum" name="maxFileNum" value="${maxNum}" />
```

this seemed not working

Answer (score 0):

`c:forEach` is used for iteration through the collections. In your case looks like you are interested in one value field. 
So if you set an attribute in your servlet like that:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.setAttribute("test", "testvalue");
    RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/test.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

You can then read it like that:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII"
    pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<title>Home Page</title>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
</head>
<body>
<input id="maxFileNum" name="maxFileNum" value="${requestScope.test}" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <input type="hidden" id="maxFileNum" name="maxFileNum" value=<c:out value='${maxNums}' />/> is this right?

Comment: If you use  type="hidden" the value cannot be shown !

Comment: please check <input type="hidden" id="maxFileNum" name="maxFileNum" value=<c:out value='${maxNums}' />/> this shows / symbol not the value

Comment: @kimchijake c:out was given just for example. You need to replace only value... see update above. So you need to type that - <input id="maxFileNum" name="maxFileNum" value="${requestScope.test}" />